# Adding Content-Encoding header to signed URL uploaded files

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I would need to upload Gziped content to S3 via a signed URL.

Here is how I generate the signed URL with a JS backend:

```
s3.createPresignedPost({
  Bucket: 'name',
  Fields: {
    key: 'key'
  }
})
```

I have tried passing the `Content-Encoding` header to the signedURL POST request but that did not work. The headers are not set properly on the s3 object.

I have also tried setting up a post upload lambda to update the metadata. It failed with an error `File is identical` error

Finally I have tried using cloudfront + a lambda to force a header. This failed too with an error stating that `Content-Enconding` is a protected error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## --Update Start--

For uploading to S3 via Ajax or JS scripts, I would advise to use `s3.getSignedUrl` method. `s3.createPresignedPost` is meant for only direct browser uploads.

Below is example of Ajax jQuery Upload I created using [this](https://gist.github.com/guumaster/9f18204aca2bd6c71a24) guide.

```
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: 'bucketName',
    Key: 'sample.jpg.gz',
    // This must match with your ajax contentType parameter
    ContentType: 'binary/octet-stream'
    /* then add all the rest of your parameters to AWS puttObect here */
  }, function (err, url) {
    console.log('The URL is', url);
  });
```

Ajax PUT Script - Take the Url from above function call and use it below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/sample.jpg.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&Content-Type=binary%2Foctet-stream&Expires=1547056786&Signature=KyTXdr8so2C8WUmN0Owk%2FVLw6R0%3D",
    //Even thought Content-Encoding header was not specified in signature, it uploads fine.
    headers: {
        'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
    },
    // Content type must much with the parameter you signed your URL with
    contentType: 'binary/octet-stream',
    // this flag is important, if not set, it will try to send data as a form
    processData: false,
    // the actual file is sent raw
    data: theFormFile
}).success(function () {
    alert('File uploaded');
}).error(function () {
    alert('File NOT uploaded');
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

In S3 object, you should see Content-Type, Content-Encoding under metadata.

**Importent Note**
When you try to upload via JS scripts which is running on browsers, typically browsers will tend to send `OPTIONS` method preflight(or CORS check) first before calling `PUT` method. You will get `403 Forbidden` error for OPTIONS since CORS on S3 bucket doesn't allow that. One way, I resolved is by using following [CORS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=137888) configuration on bucket level. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

## --Update End--

Did you try like this?. I just tested the policy using sample [html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) given in AWS documentation. Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html

```
s3.createPresignedPost({
  Bucket: 'name',
  Conditions: [
    { "Content-Encoding": "gzip" }
  ],
  Fields: {
    key: 'key'
  }
})
```

**Update** - 
Here is my observation so far.

We really need to check your client which is doing upload operation. If you want `Content-Encoding` set on MetaData, then your Pre-Signed Url should have Content-Encoding property set. If Signed Url doesn't have it but your request header does then it will give you `Extra input fields: content-encoding`.

I have signed a url with Content-Encoding and uploaded a zipped file with following sample html.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="http://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Key to upload: 
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="sample.jpg.gz" /><br />
    Content-Encoding: 
    <input type="input"  name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip" /><br />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20190108/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20190108T220828Z" />
    Tags for File: 
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='bigbase64String' />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="xxxxxxxx" />
    File: 
    <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
    <!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>
</html>
```

If I do not send `Content-Encoding` header it gives the error `Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$Content-Encoding", "gzip"]`

**Note** - 
If you are using `https` while uploading, please make sure you have proper certificate on S3 endpoint otherwise you will get cert errors.

S3 Screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I did try it and it then yield a 403 error even tho I do set the Headers on the POST request as well

Comment: @silkAdmin Can you give error response you received for 403?. Without looking at cause, which header is missing in actual upload or which header is conflicting with signature cannot be found.

Comment: @silkAdmin I understand. Do one thing, take signature you got from above method and use the sample [html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) I referred in my answer and try to upload it with that using your bucket and signature. you should see XML error response back from S3 stating what is conflicting with signature. Or if you can capture what is error response message with details coming from S3(which should say something about conflicting signature vs your upload). Or can you provide a link to your code with github to replicate at my end.

Comment: the exact error is : `Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$Content-Encoding", "gzip"]`. The request does have the correct header tho

Comment: @silkAdmin I have updated my answer based on observations so far. can you please review and advise what's happening on your side.

Comment: So do you mean that the `Content-Encoding` should be sent in the request body rather than the header? If so how is S3 going to pick this up as being meta data for the object?

Comment: @Irman so adding Content-Encoding as a field on the request does solve the 403 error however that does not add the Content-Encoding header to S3 object

Comment: @silkAdmin I added my S3 screenshot. you should have it under metadata. Please check at your end by flushing browser caching and refreshing s3 object.

Comment: Weird, this is not working for me. What part of this flow is supposed to set the metadata on the bucket ? Does AWS assume that if a file Content-Encoding is passed by the form then the according metadata has to be set on the bucket object? If so, did you see any documentation about this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186400/discussion-between-imran-and-silkadmin).

Comment: @silkAdmin Please check my updated answer with ajax script approach and let me know any feedback on above chat.