# How to decompressed the file uploaded on AWS s3 bucket having meatadata header set as- content-encoding:gzip

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

[AWS bucket model metadata(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fAFy.png)`I have obj model on s3.I set the metadata of that file as content-encoding: gzip.

I am trying to decompressed that model using zlib.But it gives me 'Z_DATA_ERROR' and 'incorrect header check`.

Here is my code:
url ="https://****/model.stl"

```
https.get(url.trim(), options, res => {
                            fetchStlMesh(res)
                        }).on('error', (e) => {
                             reject(" Additional Info : " + e);
   });
```

---

```
        function fetchStlMesh(res) {
                          const bufs = [];
                           res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                                bufs.push(chunk);
                       });
                       res.on('end', function () {
            if (this.statusCode === 200 || this.statusCode === "200") {
                 try {            
                     const data = Buffer.concat(bufs);
                     const encoding = res.headers['content-encoding'];
                         // Based on the content encoding, decode the received data
                          if (encoding === 'gzip') {
                          console.log("Unzipping the gzip file compression");
                             zlib.gunzip(data, (err, decoded) => {
                                if (err) {
                                  reject(err);
                               } else {
                                 handleStlData(decoded);
                               }
                         });
                     }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your file is a proper `*.gz` file, and not something which just has its extension set as `*.gz`? If you're unsure how to test, [here are some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload). The linked question is regarding a file about to be uploaded, but you can modify the suggested solutions - it boils down to checking the [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

Comment: file is not with .gz extension. It's normal .stl file.("https://****/model.stl")
I am just setting out the content-encoding header - gzip in aws s3 bucket after adding the model in s3.

Comment: "I am just setting out the content-encoding header - gzip" - But why would you do that? Why not `application/vnd.ms-pki.stl`?

Comment: In Amazon AWS s3 bucket there is no such option.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54067182/6133426) help in any way?